# Using jQuery, help modifying a set of urls

Tags: jquery

I am getting a selection of URLs using:

```
$("a.someclass")
```

Now my urls look like:

```
http://www....com/something/12321
```

I need to modify the urls by removing the trailing number to become:

```
http://www....com/something/
```

How can I do this?

Comment: **Just** the trailing *number*, or *everything* after the final `/` character?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work, using a regexp to remove the trailing number:

```
$("a.someclass").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', function(index, attr) {
    return attr.replace(/^(.*)\d+$/, '$1');
  });
});
```

Comment: The `^(.*)` part of the regex is unnecessary (unless you are trying to exclude URLs containing unescaped newlines, which is not likely).

Comment: @idealmachine, quite right, it should be: attr.replace(/\d+$/, '');

Comment: Additionally, the .each() function is redundant, as it could run straight from $("a.someclass").attr(...) - oh well.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this if the `href` actually ends with a number:

```
$("a.someclass").attr('href',function(i,href){return href.replace(/\d+$/,'');});
```

Comment: This is the best formation, as the each() call is obviously unnecessary - should have spotted that! :-)